# npm install in private repository inside docker not running prepare hook

Tags: linux, docker, npm, npm-install, alpine-linux

Seems like in linux prepare hook is not get called when installing from private git repository. I'm using alpine image and trying to build my private package in `npm install` but prepare hook not get called. At least if I go then into `node_modules` folder to check if lib folder is presented, it is not here.

This is sort of test dockerfile, I know that ssh keys should be injected at least through intermediate stage, in order to not leak them. Just for tests I've done it as it is.

```
FROM node:8-alpine

RUN apk --update add --no-cache openssh-client
RUN apk add git

# add credentials on build
RUN mkdir /root/.ssh/
COPY ./id_rsa /root/.ssh/
RUN chmod 400 /root/.ssh/id_rsa

# make sure your domain is accepted
RUN touch /root/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN ssh-keyscan bitbucket.org >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .
#COPY package-lock.json .

RUN npm install

COPY index.js .

ENTRYPOINT [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

Part of the code is private so I can't share it, but it is successfully get installed under windows machine and all the sequence and final package is running okay. In side this docker example it is not.

I took a look into this question 
[npm v6.4.1 not running `prepare` inside docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52766731/npm-v6-4-1-not-running-prepare-inside-docker)
But proposed solution didn't worked for me, so maybe there is something more.

How to enable prepare hook running on alpine image on `npm install`?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue for my CI pipeline. After running with `-ddd` flag, I saw the warning `prepare: cannot run in wd`. After allowing unsafe-permissions (`npm config set unsafe-perm true`) the `prepare` script was exectued, and the package built.

Source: https://npm.community/t/silent-npm-warn-cannot-run-in-wd-during-preparegitdep/8329/2